# Is there a way to apply color labels to packages in the Eclipse Package Explorer view?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, label, color-scheme, package-explorer

Is there a way to apply a color label to a package in Package Explorer in Eclipse? What I am wanting is similar to the way OSX lets you label things in Finder. I'd like to be able to quickly pick out one or two packages by giving them labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was exactly asking this same question when I found yours.
I didn't found a propper answer

However there's a way to group your projects using a tool called "working sets"

With that you can categorize and label your projects in order to quick browse & find them.

A google search of "eclipse working sets" will you show how this works

<del>The second tip of this list is a good brief explanation of how to use it
http://bwinterberg.blogspot.com/2009/09/eclipse-tips-hints.html</del>

I know It's not what you asked but it's the closest solution I found for this issue

Comment: The blogpost is not there anymore.